# DataBase design for store anketing data

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, entity-attribute-value

my English is not well, so sorry for it.
I want to write the web-app for anketing. I mean, that it must be a site, where user may give answers on different questions. For example, it can be question with text type of answer, or checkbox, or lookup (comboBox).

And my problem is in data base architecture. I read a lot about Entity Attribute Value db pattern, One True Lookup Table I also read. But these patterns has problem (with ms sql) when building a sql-query for data selecting (report).

I hope somebody give me a good suggestion, and tell, what can I do with this proplem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost everything can be represented as a string. Why not store a string in the database e.g. Text Type Answer or "true" "false" or ComboBox Value etc. Then simply convert the value from the database if necessary at runtime or in SQL if writing a query?

I feel Entity Attribute Value pattern is meant more for Entities which can have dynamic fields added etc, not so much for the problem you've posed here.

If necessary you could also add an additional column to the database table to specify the "type" of data being stored. You could then use that column to base your query convert statements on etc.

Comment: Ok. If I create table like:
Id - PK
ObjectId - (some user identificator)
QuestionId - (some question id)
AnswerVal - field of Varchar type;

For example, AnswerVal contains not string type, then I must to remember TRUE type of this field, and in the query (when I need to compare this field) make a CAST, or CONVERT. Is this a normal? I mean that a huge number of CONVERTS

Comment: I would say if the data isn't insanely large e.g. 1Million+ the penalty would be negligible. I think your only other options are to create one column for each DataType and or create one table for each answer type. The only manner to get all answers in the same table to report off of is this one. And again, I think the hit would be negligible "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MYTABLE WHERE QuestionId='abc' AND true = CAST(AnswerVal as bit) could just as easily be WHERE ... AND AnswerVal='TRUE'. You do not have to treat the value as a boolean necessarily

Comment: I know the book, that named "electronic commerce". in this book, table  has one column for each data type (IntCol, StrCol, DateCol). But I like your first suggest - to store all data in one (varchar(max)) column, and then cast its if need.

But I have another question - how can I store lookup values? Need I have ONE Lookup Table? For example - values table fields: questionId, value, type; values of fields: 1(pk);2(varchar value);lookUp(field type). The 2 - is the FK to lookupTable. Is this a right solution?

Comment: You can certainly create lookup lists to link but it would have to be a 0 to many relationship since some lookups wouldn't apply in all cases