# Database design for storing anketing data

Tags: sql, database

I want make web-app, where user can create anketa with questions, and other user can fill it with answers. Answer can be of different types: text, number, date, lookup and other. Stackoverflow's user with nick "Pepto" help me to choose the way, to build my DB ([DataBase design for store anketing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23359935/database-design-for-store-anketing-data)).

The way is to save anketa answers as rows in answers table. For example (tables design):

```
TABLE AnketaField
Id   uniqueidentifier     PK
AnketaId uniqueidentifier FK to anketa table
Name varchar              field name
Type varchar              field type (string, int, datetime)

TABLE AnketaFieldValue
Id            uniqueidentifier          PK
AnketaFieldId uniqueidentifier          FK to AnketaField table
Value         varchar                   value in string (cast to true type if need)
```

I think, if I use this design, there will be problems in selecting data, for making reports. There are to many join. 
Maybe anyone know the alternative way, or how to build system of this type (I mean different attribute number count).

I will be grateful! Thanks...

Comment: This is actually a very small number of joins. With proper indexing, you should not have any problems, performance-wise. If you want to verify this, go ahead and create those tables in your DBMS, then (using a script preferably) generate a huge amount of data (millions of records), and then run some queries, and see the results. If you encounter performance issues, play around and find ways to improve the design (indexing, partitioning, etc).

Comment: Ok, but I cant understand, if I want to select all anketa data, where user enter age 30 and gender = 'male', I need to use sub select? I'm realy very confused